# JavaScript bug: function returns NaN even though typeof function returns "number"

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-5

I want to find the largest number resulted from the permutations of a *given* number.

If the given number is 123, the largest number resulted from the permutations of it is 321.

#### EDIT

I have done some progress by changing

```
if (str.length === 0) return "";
if (str.length === 1) return str;
```

to

```
if (str.length === 0) {
    return "";
} else {
    return str;
}
```

A problem remains, however: the function returns a string. In fact, the array members are *strings* instead of *numbers*.

```js
function findPerms(num) {
    var str = num.toString();
    
  if (str.length === 0) {
        return "";
    } else {
        return str;
    }
 
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const currentChar = str[i];
    const remainingChars = str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1);
    for (let j = 0; j < remainingChars.length; j++) {
      result.push(Number(currentChar + findPerms(remainingChars)[j]));
    }
  }

    result.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a - b;
    });

  return result[result.length - 1];
    
}


console.log(findPerms(11121));
console.log(typeof findPerms(11121));
```

For this purpose I did:

```js
function findPerms(num) {
  var str = num.toString();

  if (str.length === 0) return "";
  if (str.length === 1) return str;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const currentChar = str[i];
    const remainingChars = str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1);
    for (let j = 0; j < remainingChars.length; j++) {
      result.push(Number(currentChar + findPerms(remainingChars)[j]));
    }
  }

  result.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });

  return result[result.length - 1];

}

console.log(findPerms(11121));
console.log(typeof findPerms(11121));
```

#### The problem

I must have made a mistake I was unable to spot because the function above returns **NaN** (even though `typeof findPerms(11121)` returns "number").

**Where is my mistake?**

Comment: Is your question why it returns `NaN` or why `typeof NaN === "number"` (which would be a duplicate of [Why does typeof NaN return 'number'?](/q/2801601/4642212))?

Comment: What debugging have you done? Have you tried asserting that `currentChar + findPerms(remainingChars)[j]` is always the value you expect it to be? E.g. `findPerms(remainingChars)[j]` is at some point `undefined`. Learn about [how to debug small programs](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/); [Rubber Duck Debug](//rubberduckdebugging.com/) your code and try to explain why this is.

Comment: @SebastianSimon My question is why _the function_ returns NaN instead of the biggest number in the array.

Comment: @Razvan Zamfir , what is the return type from `findPerms` ? let me guess its a empty string (`""`) or a char ("1..9") ? when you read a value from `findPerms(remainingChars)[j]` where `j` is an index, It become `undefined` , so how can you add any number with `undefiend` ?  `number + undefined = NaN`, So there is so many `NaN` value in `result` , where the last item from `result` is also `NaN`, What is your expected output value though?

Comment: **Typo:** `findPerms( remainingChars )[ j ]`  ->`findPerms( remainingChars[ j ] )`.

Comment: Though I'm not sure what you did expect your code to return, nor why 11121 is the correct result for the input 11121... Shouldn't it be 21111 instead? I.e can't your code be all rewritten to `fn = (num) => +(num+"").split("").sort((a,b)=>b-a).join("");`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of issues with your code, but let's try to define the requirements correctly first.
If I understand what you want to do is to find all permutations of a number and select the highest possible permutation of the digits in the number.
What you are trying to do is something like this:

1. Create an empty list
2. Loop through the digits of the initial number.
3. For each digit loop trough the remaining digits and find all possible combinations left and add them to the initial empty list.
4. After you have all possible combinations of numbers in the list sort them and return the highest result.

There are 2 problems here, first there are some mistakes in the execution of the code and your algorithm is not very efficient.
Let's tackle the first one:
When you create the result list you define it inside the recursive function, this means that it will be overwritten with an empty array on each recursive call. Usually when you apply this technique you either define the result array outside of the recursive function or you pass it as a argument in order to be able to iterate over the result.
You seem to not have a good grasp of how function scope and how closures work in JS. I would advise reading some resources on MDN for this.

Another problem here is that you expect the function to receive a number as argument, but when you call it in

```
result.push(Number(currentChar + findPerms(remainingChars)
```

remainingChars is a string, hence the NaN result.

Now on to the second problem. Considering that you want the highest possible number from a series of digits you could just sort the digits from highest to smallest and just provide the result.
EG:
If the number is 18, you can sort it in array like [8, 1] and then concatenate it to 81.
The code would probably look smth like:

```
function findHighestPerm(no) {
  const arr = no.toString().split('');
  return parseInt(arr.sort((a, b) => b - a).join(''));
}
```

PS: I am aware that my code is not the most efficient or elegant, but I am just lazy and it works ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**
I think this is what you would like to do.
Make an array of all digit permutations of a number using recursion.
Sort the array.
Return the permutation with the largest number.

This can be done by breaking the problem it into two functions.
The first function returns an array of all permutations of a number.
The second function takes an array result from the first function then sorts it. Then it returns the last value.
Your recursion was not operating properly. That is why it didn't work.

```
<html><head><title>6770990</title>
<script>
function findPerms(num) {
  var str = num.toString(); var result = [];
  if (str.length == 0) return result;
  if (str.length == 1) return [parseInt(str)];
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    const currentChar = str[i];
    const remainingChars = str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1)
    var perms = findPerms(remainingChars) //----Permutation array of remaining chars.
    for (var j = 0; j < perms.length; j++) {
      result.push(parseInt("" + currentChar + perms[j]));
    }
  }
  return result; //----All permutations for num.
}
function findLargestPerm(num)
{ var perms = findPerms(num); perms.sort(function(a,b) {return a-b;});
  return perms[perms.length-1];
}
</script>
</head></body>
<script>
var r = findLargestPerm(11121); alert("r=" + r);
</script>
</body></html>
```

**Previous answer**

It would be more efficient to just sort the digits in reverse order and concatenate into a number. This would be the largest permutation.

The function findPerms() is trying to find the largest permutation of a set of digits. Sometimes it helps to rename a function to what it does, so that it is easier to follow the logic.

The line that calls the function using recursion again only needs to be called once for each current character.

The following code shows the steps that happen.

```
<html><head><title>6770990</title>
<script>
var msg="";
function findLargestPermutation(num)
{ var str = num.toString(); msg += "findLargestPermutation(" + str + ")<br>";
  if (str.length === 0) return "";
  if (str.length === 1) return str;
  let result = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++)
  { const currentChar = str[i];
    const remainingChars = str.slice(0, i) + str.slice(i + 1);
    msg += "currentChar=" + currentChar + " remainingChars=" + remainingChars + "<br>";
    //----The j loop should be removed and just use this line.
    var num = Number(currentChar + findLargestPermutation(remainingChars));
    msg += "num=" + num + "<br>";
    result.push(num);
  }
  result.sort(function(a, b) {return a - b;});
  msg += "findLargestPermutation()=" + result[result.length - 1] + "<br>";
  return result[result.length - 1];
}
</script>
</head><body>
<div id="div"></div>
<script>
var lp = findLargestPermutation(11121);
alert("lp=" + lp + " typeof lp=" + typeof lp);
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML = msg;
</script>
</body></html>
```

Comment: It does not help, I'm afraid. The code does not run.